# check avaudioplayer's current playback time

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Is this the right way to check `AVAudioPlayer's` current playback time.

```
[audioPlayer play];

float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime;

float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```

How I can code after

```
  [audioPlayer play];
```

that when currentTime is equal to 11 seconds then

```
[self performSelector:@selector(firstview) withObject:nil];
```

and after firstview when currentTime is equal to 23 seconds

```
[self performSelector:@selector(secondview) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Schedule a parallel timer that checks the time. `currentTime` returns a NSTimeInterval variable, so `double seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime;` is the correct one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set up a `NSTimer` to check the time periodically. You would need a method like:

```
- (void) checkPlaybackTime:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
  float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime;
  if (seconds => 10.5 && seconds < 11.5) {
    // do something
  } else if (seconds >= 22.5 && seconds < 23.5) {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Then set up the NSTimer object to call this method every second (or whatever interval you like):

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
  target:self
  selector:@selector(checkPlaybackTime:)
  userInfo:nil
  repeats:YES];
```

Check the NSTimer documentation for more details. You do need to stop (invalidate) the timer at the right time when you're through with it:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer

**EDIT**: `seconds` will probably not be exactly 11 or 23; you'll have to fiddle with the granularity.

Comment: I don't like the 1 second boundary fences.  They seem unreliable.  Just say `if (seconds => 11) { .. performSelector:, then set some flag  indicating that even already happened. }`