# how to get current time in AVAudioplayer in a label while playing

Tags: swift, mp3, avaudioplayer, duration

I tried to build an app to play the MP3 files. I want to get current time and duration to show it in 2 labels while playing.

I used this code:

```
let duration = Int((player1?.duration)!)
let minutes2 = duration/60
let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60
durLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes2,seconds2) as String


let currentTime1 = Int((player1?.currentTime)!)
let minutes = currentTime1/60
let seconds = currentTime1 - minutes * 60
curLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
```

In duration it shows the half time of the song.

For example: 
If the duration of the song is 20 minutes and 40 seconds, it shows the half like that 10:20. But it did not make progress in the case of current time, it shows 00:00

Thanks at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
    // this is to compute and show remaining time
    let duration = Int((player1?.duration - (player1?.currentTime))!)
    let minutes2 = duration/60
    let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60
    durLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes2,seconds2) as String

    //This is to show and compute current time
    let currentTime1 = Int((player1?.currentTime)!)
    let minutes = currentTime1/60
    let seconds = currentTime1 - minutes * 60
    curLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
```

Comment: On the first line of code there is an error: `Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'TimeInterval?' (aka 'Optional<Double>') operands` as a solution, just typecast it to `Int` something like this `let duration = Int((Int(player1!.duration) - Int(player1!.currentTime)))`

Comment: @Emm what type of player you use?
AVAudioPlayer or AVplayer?

Answer (score 1):

The player's current time will not automatically update. Instead, you have to periodically update the current time using a timer. Take a look at the following thread if you want more details.

[check avaudioplayer's current playback time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525357/check-avaudioplayers-current-playback-time)

Comment: I am using swift not objective-c , any help will appreciate thanks

Comment: I know you are asking for Swift help but the code is the same. If you are interested, you should be able to figure it out very easily. All you need to know is that `NSTimer` in Objective-C is `Timer` in Swift. It should be simple enough to figure out how to convert the code ...

Comment: thanks for your answer , i asked because i am new in swift that is all

Comment: I understand, but me giving you the answer will not really help you in the long run because you'll not learn from it. Try converting the Objective-C code to Swift and see where you end up. If you run into more issues or have additional questions, ask here and I'll help.

Comment: Good luck! And if you run into any issues do ask here or start another question on SO. People will help you as long as you're willing to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Slider to seek on mp3 file, like this :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var slidetOutlet: UISlider!
```

You can update your UILabel like this:

```
     self.lblPlayerTime.text = self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Double( self.slidetOutlet.value ))
```

to initial your Player and Slider :

```
func playerInit()  {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlAudio) else {

        return
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

            player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
                if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                    let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
                    self.slidetOutlet.value = Float ( time )
                    self.slidetOutlet.minimumValue = 0

                    let duration : CMTime = self.playerItem!.asset.duration
                    let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

                    self.slidetOutlet.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
                    self.lblStartTimePlayer.text = self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: seconds)

                    self.lblPlayerTime.text = self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Double( self.slidetOutlet.value ))

                }
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

and for convert the time :

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Double) -> (String) {
    let (hr,  minf) = modf (seconds / 3600)
    let (min, secf) = modf (60 * minf)
    return ("\(Int(hr)):\(Int(min)):\(Int(60 * secf))")
}
```

Comment: User is asking for AVAudioPlayer. Your code is in AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to handle it I created a timer of 1 second for it.
Then:

1. Started at the same time we set the player to play.
2. On timer tick, set a @published variable with the player.currentTime value.
3. Invalidate the timer when the user stop or pause the player and when the audio finish playing.

Comment: This seems rahter speculative. You did never try what you are proposing as answer, right?

Comment: I did it right after posting the comment and that is actually the approach I used at the end of the day. I have it running and it’s working well.

Comment: Then I recommend to [edit] and rephrase your post into a more assertive answer.